# Is it safe in this case to remove EFI partition?

Tags: debian, linux-mint, boot

I have an old Mint (marked as "Ubuntu" below) and new Debian (with its own grub).
Partitions are as follow:

```
/dev/sda1: EFI System Partition        fat16,                  boot,esp
... 
/dev/sda6:                             grub2core.img           bios_grub
... (more partitions)
```

Contents of `/dev/sda1` partition are following:

```
EFI--BOOT-----fbx64.efi
|       |-----BOOTX64.EFI
|
|---ubuntu----grub.cfg
         |----(more grub..)
```

Note that, Debian is not there, so when I boot, if I do nothing, it boots into old Mint.

If I choose different boot options, I am able to boot into Debian with no pb ("Notebook Hard Drive" option below):
[image]

I **think** it's safe to remove ESP /dev/sda1 (and basically all other Mint partitions), but I would like a confirmation?

Comment: Your third option is probably booting via the legacy BIOS boot, but it’s worth double checking, boot into it and look to see if /sys/firmware/efi exists. If not, it’s legacy and you can delete the EFI partition.

Comment: I would keep the ESP partition, just in case you want to install in UEFI boot mode. Usually better to use UEFI with newer UEFI hardware. Query to check if UEFI or BIOS
`[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo "EFI boot on HDD" || echo "Legacy boot on HDD"`

Comment: thanks for `sys/firmware/efi` trick, I confirm the third option is booting through with legacy BIOS, while the first one is definitely UEFI